# importing stylesheets in ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

So I am trying to use this angular 2 component that's used to validate international phone numbers in my ionic 3 projects.

https://github.com/webcat12345/ngx-intl-tel-input

I did all the following said in the **[read me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we9wG.png)** from the above link.

However, my ionic project did not have (`angular-cli.json`) so I imported the required style sheets (`intl-tel-input.css`) in the in app.scss

However, it seems it has not imported the style sheets successfully..these are the following errors in the below image

[image]

anyone how I can go through this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to import from `node_modules` during runtime. As `node_modules` does not exist at runtime you have to put the css file in your `assets/css` folder and import it from there.

But I'm not sure if you need to import it manually at all. Webpack should bundle it into `www/build/main.css` automatically if you imported the components module in your `AppModule`.

Answer (score 0):

## There are two ways to import custom CSS in ionic:

1. Import from remote URL
2. Import from local directory(folder)

## Import from remote URL:

## syntax:

```
 @import url(CSS-URL)
```

## example:

```
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower&display=swap');
```

## Import from local directory(folder):

## syntax:

```
 @import url(CSS-FILE-PATH)
```

## example:

@import '../../assets/css/myFile.scss';

### Issue i faced during local css importing, i tried to import myFile.css but it doesn't worked, then i renamed it to myFile.scss it worked successfully.